# Adding Data To Firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add a new user with an empty list in my database for firebase. This is what the database looks like...

[image]

The weird sequence of characters is the user ID and the UserWatchList is an array. I want to add a new user (with their id) and an empty array but the code I have so far doesn't work and it doesn't throw any errors. Any suggestions?

```
  firebase.database().ref('users/'+userID).set({
      UserWatchList: []
  }).catch(function(error) {
      alert('Failed: ' + error);
    });
```

Comment: Firebase Database will not store a path without a value. So unless you add something in the `UserWatchList` array, it will not get written (and any existing data in `UserWatchList` will get removed).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Adding something to the array worked as you said but what if I wanted to create a path that is empty which simulates being an empty watched list?

Comment: There is no way to have a path without any value. But that's also not needed: you can add a listener to a non-existing path. If it's a `value` listener, it will fire with a empty snapshot (so `snapshot.exists() === false` and `snapshot.val() === null`) in that case.