# the function i set for my html button isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

i set a function for my button but the button doesn't follow it and it isn't being used anywhere else either

```
    <div id="main2" class="main">
        <form>
            <label class="Courier" for="EventName"></label><br/>
            <input class="Courier" required type="text" id="EventName" placeholder="Event name"><br/>
            <input class="Courier" required type="Text" id="location" placeholder="venue"><br/>
            <input class="Courier" required type="Text" id="DateAndTime" placeholder="Date and time"><br/>
            <input class="Courier" required type="Text" id="Duration" placeholder="Duration"><br/>
            <input class="courier" required type="Text" id="Clothing" placeholder="Dress code"><br/>
            <input class="courier" required type="Text" id="Food" placeholder="Food"><br/>
            <textarea class="courier" id="Notes" name="Notes" rows="4" cols="50">Enter additional notes here</textarea><br/> 
            <button id="submitEvent">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <div id="newEvent"></div>
    </div>
```

Javascript for the button below

```
$('#submitEvent').on('click' , function submitEvent(){
    var event = $('#EventName');
    var location = $('#location');
    var DateAndTime = $('#DateAndTime');
    var Duration = $('#Duration');
    var Clothing = $('#Clothing');
    var Food = $('#Food');
    var Notes = $('#Notes');

    var data ={
        event: event,
        location:location,
        DateAndTime: DateAndTime,
        Duration: Duration,
        Clothing: Clothing,
        Food: Food,
        Notes: Notes
    };
    var eventRef = database.ref('Events');
    var newEventRef = eventRef.push(data, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error Saving Data', err)
        }
        else{
            console.log('success saving data');
            $('#EventName').val('');
            $('#location').val('');
            $('#DateAndTime').val('');
            $('#Duration').val('');
            $('#Clothing').val('');
            $('#Food').val('');
            $('#Notes').val('');
        }

    })

})
```

i expect it to submit this to at least put on the console that the upload to firebase was successful or not but it doest do either it just refreshes my page to index.html and instead of the usual url it will be http://localhost:63342/Event%20Planner/www/index.html?Notes=1
when its usually
http://localhost:63342/Event%20Planner/www/index.html

Comment: Hi Daniel - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below an answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer. (You won't get any points for doing so, but that will close out the question.) *Thanks!*

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
$('#submitEvent').on('click' , function submitEvent(){
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitEvent', function(){
```

I presume you are using `.on()` because the `#submitEvent` button is added dynamically. However, you must attach the `.on` event to an element that already exists when the DOM is initially rendered -- `$(document)` is a safe and common choice.

Reference:

[Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Based on their initial HTML code, the `#submitEvent` button is already in the DOM

Comment: That's quite the assumption - a snippet of HTML was displayed. It may have been from a file/module that is dynamically loaded.

Comment: i just tried this and it didn't work. the same problem applies nothing changes just for reference all the html i have is on one file. i'm using jquerymobile data-roles so that i can have multiple pages from one file

Comment: @DanielG See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48726546/how-to-insert-update-data-in-firebase-using-javascript) also (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637445/adding-data-to-firebase-database)) and compare your firebase syntax.

Comment: @gibberish i am not using the set syntax which would but to update a field pre existing with firebase but i am using push which makes a new entry altogether. ty anyway and i will look for other posts contain the push syntax

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use the submit method https://api.jquery.com/submit/

```html
<form id="yourFormName">
            <label class="Courier" for="EventName"></label><br/>
            <input class="Courier" required type="text" id="EventName" placeholder="Event name"><br/>
            <input class="Courier" required type="Text" id="location" placeholder="venue"><br/>
            <input class="Courier" required type="Text" id="DateAndTime" placeholder="Date and time"><br/>
            <input class="Courier" required type="Text" id="Duration" placeholder="Duration"><br/>
            <input class="courier" required type="Text" id="Clothing" placeholder="Dress code"><br/>
            <input class="courier" required type="Text" id="Food" placeholder="Food"><br/>
            <textarea class="courier" id="Notes" name="Notes" rows="4" cols="50">Enter additional notes here</textarea><br/> 
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then

```
$( "#yourFormName").submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Cheers!